# Language accepted PDA

Tags: context-free-grammar, pushdown-automaton, context-free-language

Suppose we have the following PDA: `M=<Q, {0,1},{X,$}`,transition, `q0, $, F>`

```
delta(q0, 1, $) = {(q0, X$)}
delta(q0,λ, $) = {(q0, λ)}
delta(q0, 1, X) = {(q0, XX)}
delta(q1, 1, X) = {(q1, λ)}
delta(q0, 0, X) = {(q1, X)}
delta(q1, 0, $) = {(q0, $)}
```

my solution is `L(P)={w ϵ (0,1)* / 1^n 0 1^n 0 }` ... but there is another one which is `1^n 0 1^n`

which one is optimal?... Consider that the only difference between the two is clearing the first input of the PDA which is $

Thanks

Comment: _"my solution is"_. Solution to what, exactly? You want to find out the language recognized by the automaton? Also clarify the notation, there are many unclear elements, for instance, what is `F`? The terminal state?

Comment: Yes I want to find the language recognized by the automaton.... 
F: Final State ... F = Ø... automaton recognized by empty stack